# Bitwise opertor ^ on right side of equality operator == doesn't work as intended

Tags: c++

Code snippet:

```
void fn(){
    if(14-2==0^2){
        cout<<"14-2 is "<<14-2<<"\n";
        cout<<"0^2 is "<<(0^2)<<"\n";  //cout<<0^2 shows error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator<<'
        cout<<"How is if evaluated to be true?";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"else";
    }
}
```

Output:
14-2 is 12
0^2 is 2
How is if evaluated to be true?

I fixed the problem by enclosing 0^2 within () so if condition becomes

```
if(14-2==(0^2))
```

This now works as intended.

Question: I want to understand why is if evaluated to be true

Comment: See [operator_precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: FYI, different programming languages have different operator precedence rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [operator_precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence),

```
14 - 2 == 0 ^ 2
```

is parsed as

```
((14 - 2) == 0) ^ 2
```

so `(12 == 0) ^ 2`
so `false ^ 2`
so `2` (so `true`)